# @click ternary operations in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I'm trying to do the following but it keeps returning `[plugin:vite:vue] Unexpected token (1:27)` error in Vue.js:

`@click="selectedFiles.push(file.id); selectedFiles.length < 1 ? isCollapse=false: isCollapse=true"`

Basically when this image is clicked:

1. It should first push the file to selectedFiles array
2. .. and then check if the length is < 1 and change the isCollapse boolean accordingly.

The code works fine without the ternary operation so I believe it's a syntax issue.

Comment: Maybe just try to move this into an actual component `method` and see if the error still occurs?

Comment: To further expand on @Kapcash comment, it may make the code cleaner and easier to read if you move it to a method rather than inline. Personal preference here, but typically multi-line statements I always make a method for readability by other devs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually avoid the ternary entirely.

```js
isCollapse = selectedFiles.length >= 1
```

As far as ternary syntax goes spaces on either side of the colon are important.

```js
selectedFiles.length < 1 ? isCollapse = false : isCollapse = true
```

Also, I would definitely recommend using a method for this. Any time you need to perform more than 1 very simple js expression in response to an event, a method will be much more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try like:

```
@click="[selectedFiles.push(file.id), isCollapse = !!selectedFiles.length]"
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `;` rather than `,` in the middle?

Comment: @kissu hey mate, no these are functions in array.